# How to re-partition MT6582 device? (EBR1 & MBR only available) (Infinix X507)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, internal-storage, 5.1-lollipop, insufficient-memory, storage

How could I **re-partition** my **MT6582** device: [Infinix Hot X507](http://infinixmobility.com/smartphone/hot/)'s ***Internal Storage*** (also known as *Apps Storage Partition*, *System Storage*) in order to expand it (it's about 1.04GB now, and only 3MB are free)?

I don't want to use [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en), just *Internal Storage* disk re-partitioning.

The stock ROM for my device has only the files **EBR1 & MBR** (So the device seems **not** to be *EBR1 & EBR2* type).

The guides I have found are for the EBR1 & EBR2 type (not the EBR1 & MBR one) (examples: [guide 1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2596030), [guide 2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2455850)).

You can find the EBR1, MBR and Scatter files [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=4120296&d=1492745766), pulled from ROM [X507-D5120-L-20150923 Final](https://mega.nz/#!rlh0mDbL!IPXaunEjPmDCYpXVZL9wC2pS4g3rukImVkVdpVOz10g) ([ROM info](http://bbs.infinixmobility.com/thread-976-1-1.html)), currently installed Lollipop ROM on my phone.

I need to know how could I modify the both files in order to re-partition my Internal storage.